# JavaScript/HTML - Proper way to load arbitrary data file synchronously on page load

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

Since [synchronous `XMLHttpRequest`s are deprecated](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning), what is the proper way to load an arbitrary data file before the browser calls the `onload` event (and more importantly, before it scrolls to the url's #hash)?

I have a webpage that loads a markdown file and renders it to a `div`.  When a user loads the page with a hash, I need the file to be rendered before the browser scrolls to the section with the hash.  If I use an async ajax request, the browser scrolls before the markdown is rendered.  With async set to false, I get the desired behavior, but a browser warning saying that synchronous ajax calls are deprecated.

There are workarounds like scrolling to the element when the page is loaded, but when clicking forward and back through the browser history, the scroll sends you to the wrong place.  You can either detect that it's a back/forward and don't scroll (in which case, the browser tries to scroll you to the right location, but fails because the markdown hasn't been rendered), or scroll regardless of how the user got to the page, and the browser doesn't maintain the scroll position from when you left the page (inconsistent browsing behavior).

I've looked at a dozen StackOverflow questions, but they all answered what to do with async requests, rather than how to properly load a file synchronously.

### Things I've Tried

#### `<link rel="import" />`

I can use `<link rel="import" type="text/markdown" href="..." />`, and then use some JavaScript to pull out the contents and render it, but despite setting the `type="text/markdown"`, it tries to load it as an HTML document and produces a warning:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/markdown: "...".

The `link`'s `import` property is a document object with a DOM, rather than plain text, which means any HTML in my markdown document is parsed (improperly in some cases, such as when using self-closing [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements)).

#### `<iframe>`

I can use an `<iframe>` but basically have the same issue (and the same warning).  On top of that, JavaScript to manipulate the contents of the iframe and using those contents to generate elements in the containing frame becomes more complicated.

#### `<embed />`

I've tried using an `<embed>` element, but it, once again, interprets the markdown document as an HTML document despite setting `type="text/markdown"`.  In fact, it seems to have exactly the same behavior as an iframe.

Comment: Based on your use case, it would be better to build the page on the server and deliver the complete page to the browser.

Comment: Ahh, unfortunately I can't.  I'm hosting this from GitHub Pages, so I don't have access to server-side code.